# How to modify this Laravel route so that the media searches by id, but in the URL it shows slug?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

Due to this below code URL looks like: `/downloadpage/34`
I want to make URL SEO-friendly like: `/downloadpage/slug`

In table 'media' there is a column `slug`. How to change in this code that media searches by id, but in URL it shows slug?

routes.php file :

```
Route::get('/downloadpage/{id}', [
    'as' => 'downloadpage', 'uses' => 'DownloadController@index'
```

DownloadController.php file :

```
public function index($id){
    $images   = DB::table('media')->where("id", "=", $id)->get();
    $popular  = DB::table('media')->orderBy('count_download', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    $mostlike = DB::table('media')->orderBy('count_like', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    $alsolike = DB::table('media')->orderByRaw("RAND()")->where("id", "!=", $id)->take(3)->get();
    $settings = Setting::first();
    $previous = DB::table('media')->where('id', '<', $id)->max('id');
    $next     = DB::table('media')->where('id', '>', $id)->min('id');
    $imgshare = DB::table('media')->where("id", "=", $id)->first();
    return view('download.downloadpage', ['images'=>$images , 'popular'=>$popular, 'mostlike'=>$mostlike, 'alsolike'=>$alsolike, 'settings'=>$settings, 'previous'=>$previous, 'next'=>$next, 'imgshare'=>$imgshare]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that.

Route:

```
Route::get('/downloadpage/{slug}', [
    'as' => 'downloadpage', 'uses' => 'DownloadController@index'
```

Controller:

```
public function index($slug){
    $images   = DB::table('media')->where("slug", "=", $slug)->first();
    $popular  = DB::table('media')->orderBy('count_download', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    $mostlike = DB::table('media')->orderBy('count_like', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
    $alsolike = DB::table('media')->orderByRaw("RAND()")->where("id", "!=", $id)->take(3)->get();
    $settings = Setting::first();
    $previous = DB::table('media')->where('id', '<', $images->id)->max('id');
    $next     = DB::table('media')->where('id', '>', $images->id)->min('id');
    return view('download.downloadpage', ['images'=>$images , 'popular'=>$popular, 'mostlike'=>$mostlike, 'alsolike'=>$alsolike, 'settings'=>$settings, 'previous'=>$previous, 'next'=>$next, 'imgshare'=>$images]);
}
```

I changed the `$images = DB::table()...->first()` line to end with `->first()`, so you don't get an array. You'll probably need to change something in the view as well.

I would strongly recommend going through basic Laravel documentation for [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing), which explains this clearly. And going through [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) documentation and transforming your `DB` calls to Models.

Comment: By applying this changes url becomes as I want but there occurs many errors.